# What Stored Procedure can check logins (roles) information

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, metadata

SQL Server 2000.
Is there any SP can list what databases are owned by a specific login(role)?
Like:

```
EXEC sp_xxxx 'myloginname'
```

I want to see a set of database names that's owned by myloginname. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsure what you mean. So, how about these to point you in the right direction?

sp_helplogins - Provides information about logins and their associated users in each database
sp_helpuser - Reports information about the Microsoft users and roles in the current database

Comment: sp_helplogins gives the info I want. Thanks a lot.